# Wrong value when converting an array of double into an array of string

Tags: c

I want to convert an array of double into an array of string. However something went wrong after the loop.

```
double * data = {1,5,6};
int32_t n_data = 3;
char ** array;
for (j = 0 ; j < n_data ; j++) {
    sprintf(buf,"%.2f",data[j]);
    array[j] = buf;
    printf("string_array %i in loop: %s\n" , j, array[j]);
}

for (j = 0 ; j < n_data ; j++) {
    printf("string_array %i after loop: %s\n" , j, array[j]);
}
```

I was expecting to get the same printf in the loop and after the loop. However the output is somehow:

```
 string_array 0 in loop: 1.00
 string_array 1 in loop: 5.00
 string_array 2 in loop: 6.00
 string_array 0 after loop: 6.00
 string_array 1 after loop: 6.00
 string_array 2 after loop: 6.00
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: `array[j] = strdup(buf);`

Comment: Problem solved! Thanks!

Comment: You are using the same but for all your strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array[j]` stores a pointer to a `char *`. Each time you do `array[j] = buf` you are just storing the location of `buf` in `array[j]`. So, after running your code, your `array` looks like:

```
array[0] -> buf
array[1] -> buf
array[2] -> buf
```

This is why they all have the same value. They all point to the same string.

You need a new buffer for each conversion. You could call `malloc` yourself to get a new buffer each time or do `array[j] = strdup(buf);` instead.